# Easy way for read docker logs without ssh access

Tags: http, docker, ssh

Is there a way to read docker logs from a container if i don't have ssh access to the host machine?  Could i for example map the docker log command to a http port

So i could read the `docker logs` simply by do a Get request to

```
http://[dockerhost]:5234/logs
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker container's log is located at `/var/lib/docker/containers`.

E.g.

If your container's id is  `ef80f1a75417a7933912c14fd8b86ecd828cf844e9793aae81ccebbc3120c774`, then the log of the container is `/var/lib/docker/containers/ef80f1a75417a7933912c14fd8b86ecd828cf844e9793aae81ccebbc3120c774/ef80f1a75417a7933912c14fd8b86ecd828cf844e9793aae81ccebbc3120c774-json.log`.

So, you can just set a folder access for `/var/lib/docker/containers` in apache, then user can view it from browser.